# Get argument passed to a function as a string literal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

Does Ruby provide any way of obtaining an argument passed to a function as a string literal?

**In other words, if I have the following function...**

```
def my_func(arg)
   ...
end
```

**And I call my_func(obj.prop), I want to be able to obtain the following literal from within** `my_func`**...**

```
"obj.prop"
```

I know Ruby can do some pretty funky things with metaprogramming, but I haven't found a way to be able to do this just yet.

Comment: Ty but that’s not what I’m after. If argument obj.xyx gets passed to the function, I want to somehow get “obj.xyz” from it.

Comment: I'm afraid not, when we call my_func(obj.prop), `obj.prop` is executed, so we don't know what the `arg` come from. We can't call my_function("obj.prop"), right? Could you tell me more detail?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/2988).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

1. Ruby is a strict language, meaning that arguments get evaluated *before* being passed. IOW, all information about how the argument was produced is lost even before the method starts to execute.
2. There is no way to access the Ruby source code of a particular method, expression, or any other piece of code. In fact, since all Ruby implementations make it trivially easy to integrate with other languages (native extensions and FFI in YARV, mruby, and Rubinius, any JVM language in JRuby, ECMAScript in Opal, any CLI language in IronRuby, native extensions and Smalltalk in MagLev, and so on), there may not even *be* Ruby source code for a particular piece of code.
3. You want to obtain a string literal. Literals are part of a language's syntax, they don't even exist at runtime. Not only don't they exist at runtime, the very *ideas* of "runtime" and "literal" are fundamentally incompatible. Your request is not only impossible, it is non-sensical. There is no possible language, not even a hypothetical one, no possible world, in which your question would even make *sense*, let alone made to work.